# How to access wave analytics in Salesforce1 Mobie App?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I have followed steps in trail head and created an Wave Analytics account. I've also added permissions to the profiles & user.

Now, I can access Wave Analytics App in the Desktop. How can I view the Wave Analytics App in the Salesforce1 Mobile App?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have gone thru this [Wave Mobile Exploration](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/wave_mobile_exploration/wave_becoming_a_mobile_explorer) Trailhead module, you will notice that Wave Analytics App is a different mobile app from Salesforce1 mobile App.

You can install the Wave Analytics mobile app from [app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/salesforce-analytics/id916982402?mt=8)